# tried creating new project in V-play and running it but got 383 linking errors?

Tags: qt, linker, qml, v-play

tried creating new project under "empty V-play project" and running it but got 383 errors.. all starting with "declspec(dllimport)"

btw I followed [this](http://v-play.net/doc/vplay-installation.html) guide to a T in setting up V-play if it helps..

Answer (score 0):

had to switch the qt version to 2010